# Linear-programming, object function

Tags: linear-transformations, solution-verification, linear-programming, problem-solving, programming

I have this programming problem with the notation: production units i = 1,.., I there is known from data. But cost, capacity and demand are all assumed to be parameters. We denote the production cost of unit  with >0 (in USD/MWh) and the capacity is >0 (in mW). The demand is denoted as d> 0 (in MWh). Decision variables, on the other hand, are unknown (endogenous). The decisions consist of how much it takes produced on each production unit. The production level for unit i is denoted as pi ≥ 0.

I have to formulate the object function as a function of the parameters  , i = 1,... , I and the decision variables  , i = 1,. . ., I.
2)Formulate the conditions that for each unit ensure that the production level does not exceed the capacity.

Can someone help me with this problem? I maybe think that the object function is
∑=0
where  is from data and  is unknown? Or what? I'm totally new to lineary programming

I have this programming problem with the notation: production units =1,.., I there is known from data.

But cost, capacity and demand are all assumed to be parameters. We denote the production cost of unit  with >0 (in USD/MWh) and the capacity is  max >0 ( in mW  ). The demand is denoted as >0 (in MWh). Decision variables, on the other hand, are unknown (endogenous).

The decisions consist of how much it takes produced on each production unit. The production level for unit  is denoted as  ≥ 0.

1. I have to formulate the object function as a function of the parameters  :

=1,...,

And the decision variables  :

=1,...,

2. Formulate the conditions that for each unit ensure that the production level does not exceed the capacity.

Can someone help me with this problem? I maybe think that the object function is:
max∑=0
where  is from data and  is unknown? Or what? I'm totally new to lineary programming

Comment: By the way, can you give a reply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You´re almost right with the first question. Usually the goal is to minimize the cost. Thus we have

$$\textrm{min} \ \ \sum_{i=1}^I c_i\cdot p_i$$

The upper bound for the index $i$ is $I$ and it starts at $1$. Next you have the capacity constraints:

$$p_i\leq p_i^{\textrm{max}} \ \ \forall \ i\in\{1,2,...,I\}$$

Finally the non-negativity constraints: $p_i\geq 0 \ \ \forall \ i\in\{1,2,...,I\}$

Comment: Thank you very much, now it makes sence

Comment: You´re welcome.

Comment: I got a quistion more: I have to formulate the condition that ensures that the demand is met by the total production. Here we note that for electricity generation, supply and demand must be as starting point balance precisely so that neither under- nor overproduction occurs. How can I formulate that mathematically?

Comment: The supply is $\sum\limits_{i=1}^I  p_i$ And the demand is denoted as $d$. So the constraint is ...?

Comment: The note says that supply and demand must be balancing precisely so we have the constraint $$\ \ \sum_{i=1}^I  p_i=\ \ \sum_{i=1}^I  d_i$$ ? or what?

Comment: @Lifeni When I understand it right we have the (total) demand d only. So I would say that the constraint is just $\sum\limits_{i=1}^I  p_i=d$

Comment: sorry you have right. Thank you again

Comment: Nice, that we agree on that.