# Linear programming rewrite to matrix notation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-programming

I have the ED/LP-problem $$\min \sum\limits_{i=1}^{I} c_ip_i$$
Ubb $$p_i\leq p_i^{\max} \ \ \forall \ i\in\{1,2,...,I\}$$
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{I} p_i=d \ \ \forall \ i\in\{1,2,...,I\}$$
$$p_i\geq 0 \ \ \forall \ i\in\{1,2,...,I\}$$
I want to right the problem in the matrix notation.

I think we got min to $$\min(c^tx)$$.
But I can see how I can rewrite the constraints in matrix notation? can someone help me?

You can see more here: [Linear-programming, object function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3773766/linear-programming-object-function)

Answer (score 1):

You can convert equality constraints to two inequality constraints like this:
$$\sum_{i=1}^I p_i = d$$
is equivalent to
$$\sum_{i=1}^I p_i \le d$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^I (-1)\times p_i \le -d$$

In this way, all constraints are "less than" constraints so it's easy now to write them in matrix form.

---

The resulting matrix is
$$
\left[\begin{matrix}E_I\\ 1_I^T\\ -1_I^T\end{matrix}\right] 
\left[\begin{matrix}p_1\\p_2\\\vdots\\p_I\end{matrix}\right]
\le \left[\begin{matrix}p_1^\max\\p_2^\max\\\vdots\\p_I^\max\\d\\-d\end{matrix}\right]
$$

where $\left[\begin{matrix}E_I\\ 1_I^T\\ -1_I^T\end{matrix}\right]$ is expanded to $\left[\begin{matrix}1 & 0 & ... & 0\\0 & 1 & ... & 0\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\0&0&\cdots&1\\1&1&\cdots&1\\-1&-1&\cdots&-1\end{matrix}\right] $.

Comment: I don't think equality is the hard part at all

Comment: I can't not see how I can use this, can you please write the first lines in the matrix form?

Comment: @Lifeni please check the update.

Comment: Thank you, it helped me a lot

Comment: @Lifeni Feel free to accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think a way to get around it is to say

$p \in [0,p_1^{max}]*[0,p^{max}_2]*...*[0,p^{max}_n]$

and then write the equality constrain as

$1^tp=d$

One inelegant get around is

$ p_i^{max} \geq e_i^tp_i \geq 0$

Where $e_i$ is a n dimensional vector where all entry is zero except ith, which is 1.

But what is the point of doing something like that

Comment: I can't not see how I can use this, can you please write the first lines in the matrix form?

Comment: @Lifeni I can, but what is the point. Matrix notation is to keep things simple, not more complicated. Unless you have a good reason, there is no point in constraining the form.