# ED-problem solving by graph

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, linear-programming, problem-solving, programming

I got the ED/LP-problem:
$$\min\ \ \ 2p_1+4p_2$$
$$Ubb\ \ \ p_1\leq 3$$
$$\ \ \ p_2\leq 4$$
$$p_1+p_2=5$$
$$p_1+p_2 \geq 0$$
I have to solve by graph.
Can I solve it by this minimum-problem or do I have tor rewrite it to a max-problem? I have tried to draw a graph with the solution set, but how can I find the minimum (or maximum if I have to rewrite it to a max-problem)?
See the problem here: [Linear-programming, object function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3773766/linear-programming-object-function)

Comment: Do you mean $p_1+p_2\geq 0$ or $p_1,p_2\geq 0$? I think it is the second one. When you have an equality the feasible region is a line.

Comment: Sorry my faul, yes it is $p_1,p_2≥0$

Comment: No problem. Since I was sure that this was the case, I´ve posted an answer in advance.

Comment: It is unfortunate to my mind that you´ve deleted your questions.

Comment: Sorry, I got to delete both of the questions by mistake. I would not delete the post with your advice, it was a mistake. The post is up again

Comment: That´s nice. So other users can use your question if her/his question is similar.

Answer (score 1):

I´ve solved the third contsraints (equality) and $z=2p_1+4p_2$ for $p_2$. Then you draw the following graphs.

$$p_2=5-p_1, \qquad p_2=\frac{z}{4}-\frac{1}{2}p_1, \qquad p_2\leq 4,$$

and the vertical line $p_1\leq 3$.

Without the equality-constraint the feasible region is the yellow one. Only the first quadrant has been regarded due $p_1,p_2\geq 0$.

With the equality constraint the feasible region reduces to the purple line.

[image]

The blue lines are $p_2=\frac{z}{4}-\frac{1}{2}p_1$ for different value of z. It starts at $z=0$ and goes up to $z=14$. The blue line touches the purple line first at $(p_1^*,p_2^*)=(3,2)$.

The graph $p_2=\frac{z}{4}-\frac{1}{2}p_1$ has been plotted for $z=0,2,4,...,14$

Comment: Thank you very much. 
It looks like the graph I drew by hand. But now it makes perfect sense with your blue lines. So the answer is just $(p^*_1,p_2^*)=(3,2)$?

Comment: @Lifeni Yes, that´s true. And the optimal value of $z$ is $ z^*=2\cdot 3+4\cdot 2=14$. If it would have been a maximation problem the you wouldn´t have stopped. You would have went on till the blue line touches the purple line at least. This would have been the point $(p_1,p_2)=(1,4)$